# Prerender not being used in Angular

Tags: angular, express, prerender

I've been trying for some time now to get Prerender.io working in a sample Angular 6 project without success.

I succeeded in serving the application over Express, however the page doesn't get prerendered.

Here are the important files (and I can't find what I'm missing for now):

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-prerender-sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build && node server.ts",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "prerender-node": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularPrerenderSample</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
  <title>winsun - intelligente energielösungen - Steg, Chur, Baar, Vaduz, Schaffhausen, Eischoll</title>
  <meta name="description" content="winsun - intelligente energielösungen in Steg, Chur, Baar, Vaduz, Schaffhausen, Eischoll">
  <meta name="keywords" content="winsun, solar, intelligente energielösungen, energie, sonne, wallis, schweiz, steg, chur, baar, vaduz, schaffhausen, eischoll">
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="@winsun_AG">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="winsun AG">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="winsun - intelligente energielösungen in Steg, Chur, Baar, Vaduz, Schaffhausen, Eischoll">
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://winsun.ch/assets/img/logo.jpg">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="winsun AG">
  <meta property="og:title" content="winsun AG">
  <meta property="og:description" content="winsun - intelligente energielösungen in Steg, Chur, Baar, Vaduz, Schaffhausen, Eischoll">
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://winsun.ch/assets/img/logo.jpg">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://winsun.ch">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({
      appId: 'angular-prerender-sample'
    }),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

server.ts

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const project_name = 'angular-prerender-sample';

/* Prerender.io */
const prerender = require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', process.env.PRERENDER_TOKEN);
prerender.crawlerUserAgents.push('googlebot');
prerender.crawlerUserAgents.push('bingbot');
prerender.crawlerUserAgents.push('yandex');
app.use(prerender);

/* Serve the static files generated by the CLI (index.html, CSS? JS, assets...) */
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/dist/${project_name}`));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Starting the server at port ${port}`);
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on version 3.2.1 of prerender-node so you can remove these lines:

```
prerender.crawlerUserAgents.push('googlebot');
prerender.crawlerUserAgents.push('bingbot');
prerender.crawlerUserAgents.push('yandex');
```

Those user agents are included by default in v3.2.1.

When you run your server.ts file, then access a URL with the Googlebot user agent do you see the prerendered page being returned? If you are testing in your dev environment, you'll need to run our open source Prerender server and export `PRERENDER_SERVICE_URL` to http://localhost:3000/ so that it all runs locally.

You can find more info on that here: https://github.com/prerender/prerender

If you don't see a prerendered page being returned, is that server.ts file actually serving the index.html file on each request or do you have another server running for your API too?

Feel free to email us at support@prerender.io and we'll be happy to help!